# QT: manage the reply from a QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qnetworkreply

I'm new in QT development and I've to make a non-gui application that reads a token from a `POST request` and then launches some `json requests` using that token. My problem is what to do when the `finished signal` is launched. I've tried to pass the `reply.readAll()` to a `QByteArray` parameter of the object, but when I do this the value is always empty (""). My code was done based on [this](https://gist.github.com/vannell/16b8d6f4dc7e21fa0431).

.h

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class QNetworkReply;

class Downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Downloader(QObject* parent=0);

    void test();
    bool finished = false;
    QByteArray data;

public slots:
    void handleReply(QNetworkReply* reply);

protected:
    QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "downloader.h"
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>


Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(handleReply(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Downloader::test() {
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl url("http://192.168.25.25:8080/path/to/token");

    QUrl postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("client_id", "foo");
    postData.addQueryItem("username", "bar");
    postData.addQueryItem("password", "12345");
    postData.addQueryItem("grant_type", "password");

    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QNetworkReply* rep = m_manager.post(request,postData.encodedQuery());

    rep->setProperty("url", QVariant(url));
    qDebug() << "Post " << rep << rep->url();

}

void Downloader::handleReply(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    qDebug() << "Handle" << reply << reply->url();
    qDebug() << "Dynamic property" << reply->property("url").isValid() << reply->property("url");
    qDebug() << "ReadAll " << reply->readAll();
    finished = true;
    data =reply->readAll();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

In main, the call is:

```
Downloader down;
    down.test();

    while (!down.finished)
    {
        usleep(3*1000*1100);//3,3s
        cout << "no finalizado";
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the `reply` to fill a parameter and use this parameter from the `main`, when the `finished bool` is `true`. I know it's not correct, but I don't know how to manage the asynchronous nature of the request. What I need it's some guide to understand what I'm doing, since I've been searching in qt page, stackoverflow and others without success. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Downloader down;
    down.test();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You call `reply->readAll()` multiple times in `Downloader::handleReply`.  Only the first call will result in any data.

Comment: It's true. I've commented the qDebug line and now the data parameter gets the info. But the problem is the same, how and when to access this parameter from main function.

Answer (score 0):

In class `Downloader`, declare a signal to emit the `data` to a slot of another QObject derived class. For example, in `Downloader::handleReply` you call `emit dataReady(data)`. In the main function add below code:

```
Downloader down;
JsonSender obj;
connect(&down, &Downloader::dataReady, &obj, &JsonSender::dataReady);
down.test();
return a.exec();
```

In the slot `dataReady` of class `JsonSender` you can parse the token and send the request.